# Object doesn't support property or method jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I'm trying to extend a existing jquery plugin as following.

```
 $.fn.cslide = function (options) { //added options & settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        Model : null
    })
    this.each(function () {
        //init code etc etc
        var modelDataJSON = null;

        if (settings.Model) {
            modelDataJSON = settings.Model;
        }
        //function declarations and implementations
    }
}
```

So all good so far. But when I run this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#cslide-slides").cslide(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
</script>
```

He doesn't recognize the JSON and returns

> Object doesn't support property or method

as error. It's my first time extending an existing jquery plugin so I followed the following guide.

[Jquery Plugin Tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/writing-your-own-jquery-plugins)

Could any of you kind people point me in the right direction.

I tried following things

- Sending string through
- Sending static json through
- `$("#cslide-slides").cslide({ @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not passing along the `options` object as a second parameter in the *extend* statement. Furthermore, you best terminate that statement with a semicolon

```
var settings = $.extend({
    Model : null
}, options);
```

Since `$.extend` effectively merges the contents of the object parameters that follow, you'll always need at least two parameters for the statement to make sense.

Comment: The semicolumn was there. Copy paste fail I guess